# Maven SNAPSHOT versions for transitive dependency

Tags: maven, dependency-management

If in a spring boot project, A has library b as dependency and B has library C as dependency (C is transitive dependency in A) and I am using snapshot versions. When I build A it looks for snapshot versions for its direct dependency but for C, it looks for version without snapshot.

How to solve this?

Comment: Sorry, this is way to vague. Maven looks for the dependency version as it is defined, and if there are several versions, there is a mediation mechanism. To answer your question, you would need to be much more specific.